# Return type of lambda in C++11 from inside the lambda (flat map function)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have implemented a function insipired on scala's flat map and I wonder if I can access the return type of the lambda inside the lambda to avoid repeating it when using it

```
/**
 * Inspired on scala's flat map, provide a @param func which output will be flattened in the output
 * sequence, which is the return type of @param func
 */
template <typename IN, typename F>
auto flat_mapf(const IN& input, F func)
    -> decltype(func(std::declval<typename IN::value_type>()))
{
    decltype(func(std::declval<typename IN::value_type>())) output;
    auto outit = std::back_inserter(output);
    for (auto i = input.begin(); i != input.end(); ++i)
    {
        decltype(func(std::declval<typename IN::value_type>())) interm = func(*i);
        std::move(interm.begin(), interm.end(), outit);
    }
    return output;
}


// usage example, I would like to avoid repeating vector<size_t> type two times:
auto vo = flat_mapf(vi, [](const size_t& x) -> vector<size_t> {
    vector<size_t> res;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x; ++i)
        res.push_back(x);
    return res;
});
```

Comment: Huh? So you want to avoid the `vector<size_t>` in the line `vector<size_t> res;`?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think return type for lambdas is optional.

Comment: Wow. What bugs you is that you have to repeat `vector<size_t>` twice, and not the huge `decltype` in `flat_mapf`? As a note: `auto interm = func(*i);`.

Comment: @Xeo - understandable that a library author is more concerned about the experience of *users* of `flat_mapf` than about what its internal implementation looks like. There are many more uses than implementations (especially here, as `flat_mapf` is the monadic "bind" operation).

Comment: @Daniel: Except that a lambda is not part of the library, so there is nothing the library author can do.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just omit the `-> vector<size_t>` from the usage example, so the compiler infers the return type of the lambda? That way you only say the type once.

Comment: The lambda body is not `return expr;`, so this doesn't work, no.

Comment: @Xeo - interesting that Visual C++ supports it just fine. Is it a MS-specific extension?

Comment: That won't work in his case, I think, since the return type deduction for lambdas only works under very strict circumstances (only one-liners, I think, though I also remember that this was loosened a bit lately, not sure).

Comment: Well, it's planned to allow multiple statments and still infer the return type for the next standard, but currently, yes it's an extension (which is also supported by GCC and Clang IIRC). :)

Comment: I guess all the compiler implementers are reading Wikipedia instead of the standard then! "The return type of a lambda can be omitted as long as all return expressions return the same type." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions

Comment: @Daniel: Or they follow [the proposals](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3386.html) and [defect reports](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#975) for the next standard. ;)

Comment: Indeed! It is very strange that the standard didn't already specify it this way - almost like it would be *more* work for compiler authors to put in the restriction than to leave it loose.

Comment: The committee is very conservative about adding new features where no one knows the implications. Instead, they add it in a restricted form and lift those restrictions later on, which is easier than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Since the functionality you want to provide works on ranges (which is a very reasonable thing), I can point you to Boost.Range. A user would be able to combine your `flat_mapf` with e.g. `boost::irange` like so:

```
auto vo = flat_mapf(vi, [](size_t x) {
    return boost::irange(size_t { 0 }, x);
 });
```

(`boost::irange` only works over integral types, `boost::counting_range` is more general.)

Answer (score 0):

Returning an actual vector may not be the right approach here.  That requires all of the output from each element to be produced and cached before it is accumulated together.

A generator pattern of some kind, such as a sub map functor that returns a boost optional (empty meaning finished generating) or the like would mean you would not require the intermediate container.  Turning such a generator into a std vector is easy, and writing flat map when each of the sub maps is a generator lambda is also easy.

I bring this up because it also means the double type specification goes away.  In situations where a trinary operator does not work, you just have one location returning for and then other returning empty.

In short maybe you are typing std vector a lot because you are making a lot of std vectors.

Comment: I tried boost::optional before, looks a good idea but it's a pain in the ass to use in the debugger. I'll avoid that overengineering in the future, for me optional now is just a pointer that can be null. At least I can inspect it easily.

Comment: That requires using the free store usually, and all the headache that implies.  My point is that generators (of whatever kind -- there are many ways to do it) may be a better approach than `vector`-builders when emulating functional programming behavior in C++.  Functional language often pull data rather than push it.

Comment: Could you post a concrete example of what you mean? Is not like it's so easy to express a generator in C++. In python I know how to do it with yield etc.